# how to get salesforce current page URL in salesforce apex by javascript

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I need salesforce current page URL which has been displayed in address bar of browser.

[image]

I want to put this url instead of `{URL}` in src of Iframe as given below

```
<apex:iframe src="https://example.com/Authentication.aspx?from=salesforce&redirectpagename={URL}&useremail={!$User.Email}" scrolling="true" id="scIframe" />
```

Thank you

Comment: use `window.location.href ` to get current page url

Comment: I am using Iframe so if I am using window.parent.location.href but it gives cross origin error

Comment: try`document.getElementById("scIframe").contentDocument.location.href`